# view will/did appear called when reappearing

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, ios8

Is it just me or everyone observes the same? It seems in XCode6/iOS8 sdk the "back" viewController's viewWill/DidAppear:animated messages called after the "front" and presented viewController is popped out.

I remember clearly in XCode5/iOS7 sdk the two were not called when reappearing.

I created a brand new test project (master/detail template), added only 6 lines of codes:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  NSLog(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  NSLog(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the situation with dismissing a modal VC? If so, then I think the presenting VC's `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` are called when the modal is dismissed even in iOS7.

Comment: what i mean is popViewController. After do popViewController, the re-appearing vc's viewDid/WillAppear:animated get called.

Answer (score 0):

That has been the expected behavior of `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` ever since their introduction. They get called when the view ... **appears**.

Comment: NO, according to Apple's doc: `This method is called before the receiver's view is about to be added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured for showing the view.`

Comment: That's a mistake then. Use viewdidload and viewdidunload.